# Assigning ironpython method to C# delegate, this method will be passed across appDomains

Tags: c#, delegates, ironpython, appdomain

Consider the following scenario:

AppDoamin 1:

```
public delegate bool Delegate1(class1 c1,string p);

 class class1
  {
    public bool method1(Delegate1 d, out IEnumerable<string> partNumbers)
      {
      //Method body
       }
    }
```

AppDoamin2:

```
class x
 {
  public bool method2(Dictionary<string,string> x,out string[] returnValues)
   {
    class1Instance.method1(delegate(class1 cc,string pp){if(x.Key=="blaah") return False;},out temp);

    }
  }
```

IronPython Script:
calls method 2.

This approach is giving serialization exception as delegate in appDomain2 is using variables from stack.

Possible solution:
Pass the delegate method from ironpython script to method in appDomain2 which is passed as it is in Appdomain3.

Problem:
How to do this? Till now not able to search anything on this.

NOTE: .NET Framework 2 and ironpython 2.7.1 is used.

P.S. Sorry for Poor formatting!

Comment: Does the scenario work without IronPython across app domains?

Comment: I am NOT able to do this with ironpython involved but Sending Delegate method from AppDoamin3 created in .Net works fine. If only C# is involved then problem boils down to NOT using stack variable inside delegate i.e use only Local Variable.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the problem. The closed over variables are not serializable. Not sure how to fix this. The only option I can think of is creating a remotable wrapper for the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. As generally happens answer is sweet and Simple!

So created a small helper class which encapsulates the whole delegate implementation, member variables etc. Constructor for this class takes in parameter necessary(Which were causing problems of NOT being able to serialize the delegate).Following is the small helper class i wrote-

```
public sealed class DevCatalogFilterHelper : MarshalByRefObject
{
    Dictionary<string, string> m_resourceNameValuePair;

    public DevCatalogFilterHelper(Dictionary<string, string> resourceNameValuePair)
    {
        this.m_resourceNameValuePair = resourceNameValuePair;
    }

    public  bool FilterDelegate(class1 devCat,string partNumber)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in m_resourceNameValuePair)
        {
            string value;
           //if(condition){helpFull code return false;}
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: As I said, a remotable wrapper :) Glad you found your solution.